# How to set JSON validation schema for general properties values

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to validate JSON using schema (currently draft 6, but we could upgrade if needed). My case is an object with properties whos values all have the same structure, e.g.:

```
{
  "blueFoo": {
    "bar1": "someValue",
    "bar2": "differentValue"
  },
  "redFoo": {
    "bar1": "someOtherValue",
    "bar2": "LoremYpsum"
  },
  "purpleFoo": {
    "bar1": "anotherString",
    "bar2": "nextValue"
  },
  ...
}
```

is there a way to set validation schema for general property values? Something like:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "propertyValue": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["bar1", "bar2"],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "bar1": {"type": "string"},
      "bar2": {"type": "string"}
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`additionalProperties` is exactly for that purpose:

```
{
 "type": "object",
 "additionalProperties": {
    "properties": {
      "bar1": {"type": "string"},
      "bar2": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "required": ["bar1", "bar2"],
    "additionalProperties": false
 }
}
```